# Laravel Resource return true if relationship exists

Tags: laravel, model, resources

I am building a pretty nice RestAPI in Laravel including Resources. Now I`m a little bit struggeling with this:

my model is arranged by this function

```
public function friendship(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Friendship');
}
```

In resource I`calling

```
'friendships' => $this->friendship()->get()
```

So I`m getting all "friendships". Works. But I just want to know if there is a friendship. How does my model then have to look like?

I tried following but does not work

```
if($this->hasOne('App\Models\Friendship'){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exists` method to determine the existence. Consider the following snippet;

```
`friendship` => $this->friendship()->exists(),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution take me to right solution. $this->friendship()->exists()